# Trace property of $H_0^1(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace-map

Do we have:
$$
H_0^1(\Omega)=\{f\in H^1(\Omega): \gamma f=0\},
$$
while $\gamma:H^1(\Omega)\rightarrow H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is the trace map?

The teacher says that it's true in the course, without giving a proof. I have checked the textbook and searched for a proof, but failed. I understand that "$\subset$" is obvious but how about "$\supset$"? How to say some function can be approximated by $C_c^\infty$?

More genearlly, do we have:
$$
H_0^m(\Omega)=\{f\in H^m(\Omega):\gamma_jf=0,\quad j=0,\cdots,m-1\}
$$
while $\gamma_j:H^m\rightarrow H^{m-j-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial\Omega)$ are trace maps?

Comment: What is your definition of $H_0^1(\Omega)$? The result you ask about is what I'm aware of as being the definition of $H_0^1(\Omega)$, hence there would be no way to "proof" it.

Comment: Perhaps try the following: Any function in $f \in H^1$ can be approximated by a sequence of functions $g_n \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ in the $H^s$-norm. Then by the continuity of the trace operator $\|\gamma f - \gamma g_n\|_{H^{1/2}} \longrightarrow 0$. Now try to modify the $g_n$ so they are actually compactly supported in $\Omega$ and use that their trace becomes small to show that they still have the same limit in $H^s$.

Comment: @FelixCrazzolara $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is usually defined to be the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ under $H^1$ norm, while $H^1(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty(\Omega).$ If the proposition is true, then two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @RobertWegner Thanks. At first I want to find $g_n$ itself is compact, but forget to try to  modify it to have compact support. I think cut-off functions and mollifier will work.

Comment: It should be said that all of this trace stuff requires a Lipschitz boundary, if I recall correctly. You might have to use the local Lipschitz parametrized representation of the boundary to construct the modified $g_n$. Maybe $C^1$ boundary is a better start.

Comment: There Thm 2 in Section 5.5 of Evans' book. The proof is sufficiently technical.

Comment: @daw Thanks a lot. I forget to check this book.